# PlayWright - TypeError: browser.newPage is not a function

Tags: javascript, playwright

When ever I am trying to run the code I am getting error "TypeError: browser.newPage is not a function". Here is my code

```
const {chromium} = require('playwright');
(async() => {
const browser = chromium.launch({
    headless:false
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
await browser.close();
})();
```

If I change the code to the following then I am able to run the code but url is not getting open whatever I am providing, Just browser is getting open and close.

```
const playwright = require('playwright');
(async () => {
  for (const browserType of ['webkit']) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch({
        headless:false
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage('https://www.google.com');
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

I am using Playwright version 1.20.0
node.js version is v16.14.0

Comment: In the first example you are missing the "await statements" and in the second example you are not using the Playwright API correctly. You need to call page.goto. See here: https://playwright.dev/docs/next/library

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page = await context.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

You might want to check out the documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/1.19/intro#first-test